# How can I merge all tables within a single sqlite3 database?

Tags: database, python-2.7, sqlite

I have a single database of over 9,000 tables, built by ingesting an enormous dataset. Each table can vary in size, but the columns of each table are the same (day, month, year, time, measurement, altitude).

How can I do this? I've read that using a single table will be much more efficient for me to query for, say, all measurements within a specific month. Rebuilding the database itself would be a pain, and would take too much time.

Comment: How are the table names determined?

Comment: Short answer: Dataset_(number).  E.g. "Dataset_1008", "Dataset_1009", etc.

Long answer: This is based on how I extracted data from an embarrassingly large number of text files, and didn't know details about the dataset, only the information (day, month, year, measurement) that was taken.

Comment: Is that number important in any way, i.e., do the measurements need to be associated with that number?

Comment: Nope.   As long as all information from each row stays together, i don't care how the tables are merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the list of tables, execute the following SQL statement for each table:

```sql
INSERT INTO Dateset_all SELECT * FROM Dataset_123;
```

Comment: I tried this method. I built a list of all table names, and then did something like... for tablename in tablelist:   /    c.execute("INSERT INTO Dataset_all SELECT * FROM %s" % tablename)    /    conn.commit().  When I go to check the "Dataset_all" table, it certainly does not contain all the elements of the other thousands of tables.  Suggestions on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

# close connection
conn.close()

Comment: What elements are missing?

Comment: Oh, god. I just now saw in firefox's sqlite3, that the number of pages changed dramatically. It worked great! Thank you so much. Upvoted!